# Proper way to fill an html array using django/python

Tags: arrays, django, templates

I encounter a small issue about filling my html array in a django template.

I wanted to print one form to one row. Instead of one row to all forms ( that's what i get with the sample code just right there ) :

```
 <thead> <!-- cétait td à la place de th -->
            <tr>
            {% for entry in headers %}
            <th>
            {{ entry }}
            </th>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>             

          </thead>
          <tbody>

                <tr>
                {%for entry in entries%}
                {%for cle, valeur in entry.all_form_entry_json%}
                {%for key, valor in headersLoop%}
                {%if key == cle%}

                 <td> {{valeur}}</td>


                {% endif %}

                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}                   
                {% endfor %}                    
                </tr>

          </tbody>
```

The result is such as follow :

[image]

You can notice that all the datas are printed to the right corner and go beyond the array limit.

How can i have a result like this ?

[image]

Is this possible to do it only with html ? Or should i create a js or css file and import it to this template.html ?

Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just wrong place for the html `<tr>` tag,
the tag `<tr>` should inside `{% for` loop..

```
<thead>
  <tr>
  {% for entry in headers %}
    <th>{{ entry }}</th>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
{% for entry in entries %}
  <tr>
    {% for cle, valeur in entry.all_form_entry_json %}
      {% for key, valor in headersLoop %}
        {% if key == cle %}
          <td>{{ valeur }}</td>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```